# How do I save user information (like NSUserDefaults in obj-c) with C++?

Tags: c++, file, memory

In objective-c it's easy. Although, in C, you have to call fopen, read, close and all of that jazz. How do you do it in C++?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is a Cocoa class, not an Objective-C feature. The asnwer may depend on which C++ framework (if any) you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use the header fstream
example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ofstream file;
file.open("file.txt");
file << "Test!\n";
file.close()
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am rather confused when you say ofstream file

Comment: For instance, say I want to make a game that saves data to a file, so that even after the user closes the application, they can access their information. How would I save the user information?

Comment: @Monkeyanator: That reads roughly `create an object called file of type std::fstream`.

Comment: @Monkeyanator when i call a ofstream, it's a file handle. so i can proceed to open a file, when i say "ofstream file;" that means i made a file handler named "file" then i can use that handle to open files, write to them, and close them.

Comment: it says cannot open file or pdb

Comment: @Monkeyanator yeah, and if you want to read a file you would use "ifstream file;" good luck!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4010/discussion-between-code-monkey-and-monkeyanator)

Comment: hey i'm back, look at ur chat